# Web.py pass parameter to GET/POST function via ajax call on form submit

Tags: python, web.py

I have a main page that has a `GET` and a `POST` function. The `POST` function gets data from a search screen and should pass this information, via an ajax call, to the `worldMarkers` class. This is separate because it will be needed for other aspects of the application.

The goal of this, is to have a user press submit on `index` and during the `POST` call, it is able to limit the results retrieved. This logic exists in the `worldMarkers` class.

```
class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        # do things to generate the page
        return html

    def POST(self):
        continents = web.input(search_continents=[])
        countries = web.input(search_countries=[])

        searchDict = {}
        if continents['search_continents']:
            searchDict['continents'] = continents['search_continents']
        if countries['search_countries']:
            searchDict['countries'] = countries['search_countries']

        markers = worldMarkers()

        # Yes, this just spits out the results, nothing fancy right now
        return markers.GET()

        #alternatively,
        #return markers.GET(searchDict)



class worldMarkers(object):        
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.searchDict = None
        if 'searchDict' in kargs:
            self.searchDict = kargs['searchDict']

    def GET(self):
        print "SearchDict: %s" % (self.searchDict)
        # No searchDict data exists
```

The first option, with no parameters to `markers.GET()` means that none of my search criteria has been passed. If I do `markers.GET(searchDict)`, I receive this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /
GET() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How can I pass my search parameters to the `worldMarkers` class?

Comment: `def GET(self, search_dict)`, and in the function use `print("SearchDict: %s" % search_dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should actually create an instance of `worldMarkers` as follows in order for your searchDict to exist:

```
markers = worldMarkers(searchDict=searchDict)
```

Right now, you're creating it without the argument:

```
markers = worldMarkers()
```

and in that case, the condition `if 'searchDict' in kargs` is false and `self.searchDict = kargs['searchDict']` is not run.

And, as @TyrantWave points out, your GET is not really prepared to take any arguments since it is only declared as `def GET(self)`. See the last sample code of [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) of the docs.

Comment: For `searchDict` to exist in the instance, it needs to be created like `markers = worldMarkers(searchDict=searchDict)`, as the init expects a keyword argument.